# Scikit-Learn windows Installation error : python 2.7 required which was not found in the registry

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, enthought, epd-python

I have installed Enthought Canopy 32 - bit which comes with python 2.7 32 bit . And I downloaded windows installer scikit-learn-0.13.1.win32-py2.7 .. My machine is 64 bit. I could'nt find 64 bit scikit learn installer for intel processor, only AMD is available.

Python 2.7 required which was not found in the registry is the error message I get when I try to run the installer. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enthought Canopy 1.0.1 does not register the user's Python installation as the main one for the system. This has been fixed and will work in the upcoming release.